# Change Orientation on only one View Controller , lock others to portrait mode (xcode 6.2)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, orientation

I have used the AMSSlideMenuController to create my main VC

```
@interface LoggedIn_MainVC : AMSlideMenuMainViewController
@end
```

And In App Delegate I create it using:

```
//start first vc
    self.mainVC = [[LoggedIn_MainVC alloc] init];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

In LoggedIn_MainVC, I create Left and Right Menu both using AMSSlideMenuTableViewController, like so:

```
@interface LeftMenuVC : AMSlideMenuLeftTableViewController
```

and they both are instantiated like so in LoggedIn_MainVC:

```
*******************************/
self.leftMenu = [[LeftMenuVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftMenuVC" bundle:nil];
self.rightMenu = [[RightMenuVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RightMenuVC" bundle:nil];
/*******************************
```

In the Left Menu, I have StartPageView, VideoPageView, and SettingsView. I want to lock all other views to portrait mode except for VideoView.
The LeftMenuVC:

```
#pragma mark - TableView Delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- {UINavigationController *nvc;

UIViewController *rootVC;
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
    {
        rootVC = [[VCLoggedIn_StartPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"VCLoggedIn_StartPage" bundle:nil];
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        rootVC = [[VCLoggedIn_Levels alloc] initWithNibName:@"VCLoggedIn_Levels" bundle:nil];
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        rootVC = [[VCLoggedIn_Videos alloc] initWithNibName:@"VCLoggedIn_Videos" bundle:nil];
    }
        break;
    case 3:
    {
        rootVC = [[VCLoggedIn_Settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"VCLoggedIn_Settings" bundle:nil];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];

[self openContentNavigationController:nvc];
}
```

I am using in Appdelegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window 
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight; 
}
```

and for videoView:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
} 
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

For OtherViews:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

All the views are behaving equally (both landscape and portrait). however I have found that when I put this orientation mode in LoggedIn_MainVC (the mainView Controller):

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}
```

All the other views are behaving the way this function(supportedInterfaceOrientations) in LoggedInMainVC is defined. When I change to just UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait, all views have only portrait mode and viceversa. Their own definition of supportedInterfaceOrientations is not working. 
What am I missing or doing wrong. 
Please Help Me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

in `videoView` to make it landscape

Comment: thanks for the suggestion...but still not working..same problem